# TableView select multiple rows

Tags: ios, tableview

I am using this code to select a specific row in a `tableView`

```
tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
```

But how can I select multiple rows, or set all rows at selected?

I tried in `cellForRowAt indexPath` to use `isSelected = true` and `isHighlighted = true` before I return each cell but it didn't worked.

Comment: Add this in viewDidLoad method,  tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

Comment: it's so. I can select different rows with tableView.selectRow(at

Comment: better you apply code then we can discuss

Comment: update me , Is it salved or still you are stuck at this.

Comment: J.Doe is my answer is working?

Answer (score 1):

```
tableView.isediting = true
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just maintain an array of selected rows and check them in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and then return the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your table allows multiple selections, then...

```
    // select ALL rows in Section 0
    for i in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) {
        let iPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
        tableView.selectRow(at: iPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }

    // select ALL VISIBLE rows
    for iPath in tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows! {
        tableView.selectRow(at: iPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }

    // select rows 2, 4 and 6
    for i in [2, 4, 6] {
        let iPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
        tableView.selectRow(at: iPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
```